# SQL query used to create table has unique constraint, but the data for that column is not unique

Tags: sql, duplicates, constraints, ssms, unique

```
create table table1 (
   table_identifier integer identity,
   routing_identifier integer not null,
   account_code char(4) not null),
   constraint pk_table1 primary key (table_identifier),
   constraint ak_table1 unique (routing_identifier, account_code)
```

I inserted data myself by creating random test data, and the data I have inserted in `routing_identifier` and `account_code` have duplicates in them. I didn't notice until now that both of those columns have many duplicates in the test data I created. I'm not sure why it didn't error out stating unique key, no duplicates allowed or something. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Do you mean that you have multiple identical **combinations** of `routing_identifier, account_code` values?

Comment: What is your question? What problem you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

`unique (routing_identifier, account_code)` means that the combination of `routing_identifier` and `account_code` should be unique, not that they are both unique on their own right. E.g., consider these three unique pairs: (1, 10), (2, 10) and (1, 20) - each of these pairs is unique, but neither `routing_identifier` nor `account_code` are unique on their own right.

If you want each of these columns to be unique, you should define two separate unique constraints:

```sql
create table table1 (
   table_identifier integer identity,
   routing_identifier integer not null,
   account_code char(4) not null),
   constraint pk_table1 primary key (table_identifier),
   constraint ak_routing_identifier_table1 unique (routing_identifier), -- Here!
   constraint ak_account_code_table1 unique (account_code) -- And here!
)
```